# Data inserting as ASCII Values using JDBC 2.0 Result set Updater methods

Tags: java, jdbc, jdbc-odbc

I am trying to insert the data using JDBC 2.0 with `Resultset` `update` methods with Type 1 Driver. But I am checking in the table, it inserted data as ASCII values. I mention the code below:

```
try {
    stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    rs=stmt.executeQuery("select ENO,ENAME,EADD from Employee");
    String name="saikiran";
    rs.moveToInsertRow();
    rs.updateString("ENO","3");
    rs.updateString("ENAME",name.toString());
    rs.updateString("EADD","CSE");
    rs.insertRow();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If the same code is run using Type 4 Driver, its working fine. What's the problem with Type I Driver using `ResultSet` `update` methods?

Comment: What is the expected behaviour? Some other character encoding?